# How to copy particular line of csv file to a new csv file?

Tags: linux, csv

I have a csv file which contains 50 million+ records.
I want some particular lines from that file to another new csv file.
The lines which I need to copy are random i.e I have to search for a particular value and then copy.
I am working on linux.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you know how to search for your lines? And when you want to copy them, do you want to append to the existing file or do you want to do some replacement? What do you want to replace? ... In top of that, please show us what you've tried already.

Comment: I have a file abc.csv which contains 50million+ rows. I have to process that file. But before that what I need is I will select some 10 specific rows for processing. So i need that 10 records to be inserted in new csv file so that it can be processed quickly. Suppose a row contain value XYZ . So i have to search for that value and insert that row in the new file

Answer (score 0):

What about a awk command like this (example with the second field being the one you are looking at):

```
the_value_you_want=some_specific_value
awk -vvalue=$the_value_you_want -F, '$2 == value { print $0; }' < input_file > output_file
```